# getting out of an aborted rebase in git

Tags: git

I was trying to do a rebase and then aborted. Now my git directory says `(branchname|REBASE-i 1/15)`. So I checked out master and then did `git branch -D branchname` and git is still saying `(branchname|REBASE-i 1/15)`.

How can I fix this? I tried `git gc` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `git rebase --abort` again.

Otherwise `git reset --hard {ref}` will get you out of trouble.

Use `git reflog` to find the reference point just before you started the rebase. Then use it in place of {ref} in the second command e.g. `git reset --hard 0ac372`

Don't worry about the reset command, you can always go back to where you were before you did the reset using the same command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell git that you want to abort.

```
git rebase --abort
```

This will restore your working copy to the state just before you did `git rebase`.